# Can storing large variables in a closure cause problems?

Tags: javascript, closures

I have a function in which I'm using closure as follows:

```
function myobject() {
  var width=300,
      height=400,
      bigjsondata = { } // assume this is a big variable ~ 300k

  function obj(htmlelement) {
     // plot a graph in this htmlelement based on bigjsondata
  }

  return obj;
}

var plot1 = myobject();
plot1('#holder1');

var plot2 = myobject();
plot1('#holder2');
```

the variable `bigjsondata` contains a large dataset. The question is: does it allocate memory for `bigjsondata` whenever I create a variable `var a = myobject()` ?

Can it lead to memory problems if a lot of instances are created?

If so what is the best way to load it only once? (`bigjsondata` does not change)

**Edit:** At the end I would like `myobject` to be globally accessible.

Comment: Yes; Yes; Use only one (less local scoped) variable

Comment: Why do you say that `bigjsondata` does not change when `obj.data` is a setter function for it?

Comment: oh my mistake I should remove the the setter function.

Comment: Are you sure that `myobject` should return the `obj` function?

Comment: what do you do in the obj function. If you could provide us the proper code, we could suggest you a better approach.

Comment: @ParthikGosar I added some extra code and comments.

Comment: Is 300K really a big object? Quite a few images are a lot larger than this!

Comment: @EdHeal Well thats not the point of the question and I wonder why would it be needed to store in image in such place!

Comment: @Nasir - The point is that 300K is not "big". Browsers do chuck around images/data of similar sizes without any problems. Also the Javascript engine has mechanisms to reduce the impact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not sure what you are trying to achieve, this should provide you with some private storage on different levels:

```
var privateStorage = function () {
  // only 1 copy total
  var bigJsonData = {...}
  return function() {
    // 1 copy for each instance
    var instanceData = {...}
    return function() {
          // something to do many times per instance
          return something_useful
    }
  }
}(); // returns function that privatelly knows about bigJsonData

var a = privateStorage(); // a is now 1st instance of the inner-most function
var b = privateStorage(); // a and b share the SAME bigJsonData object, but use different instanceData objects

a1 = a();
a2 = a();
```

Comment: +1 for returning the function rather than what I used in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Generally - yes, you code looks like creating a new instance for the `bigjsondata` each time you make a `new myObject();` To get arround the issue, you can use anonymous initialization function like this:

```
myObject = null;

(function() {
     var bigjsondata = { ... } // construct you large object here;

     function myObjectInternal() {
         // you can access `bigjsondata` from here.
         // do not change `bigjsondata`, since it will now 
         // use the changed value in all new instances of `myObjectInternal`
     }
     myObjectInternal.prototype = {
         data: function(_) {
             // you can access `bigjsondata` from here too
         }
     };

     myObject = myObjectInternal;
})();
```

This will create an anonymous function that is called immediately and only once (like a singleton). Inside the function, `bigjsondata` is a a closure to the `myObjectInternal` function, which is visible only in the anonymous one. That is why you define the outer global variable `myObject`, to latter make it point to the `myObjectInternal`  function/object.

Define `myObjectInternal` as you would have `myObject` and you're good to go. So, in the following code:

```
var instance1 = new myObject();
var instance2 = new myObject();
```

it will use the same `bigjsondata` for `instance1` and `instance2`

Comment: can you give an example code of how exactly you can access bigjsondata from the `instance1` and `instance2`?

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz, the code above does not expose the `bigjsondata`, and the OP's question at the time of answer did not imply it should be exposed. If you require it, you need to provide a getter function in the `myObject` prototype like this:  `myObjectInternal.prototype.getData = function() { return bigjsondata; }` and then you can call `instance1.getData();` to get it.

Comment: Yep, I know that the question was changed in the meantime. But thanks to this code - now I understand the idea, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest going for an object oriented approach for this.

```
function obj (htmlelement)
{
    this.htmlelement = $(htmlelement);    
}

obj.prototype.htmlelement = null;
obj.prototype.bigjsondata = {};
obj.prototype.width = 300;
obj.prototype.height=400;

obj.prototype.plot = function ()
{
   var htmlelement = this.htmlelement;
   var bigjsondata = this.bigjsondata;
   var width = this.width;
   var height = this.height;
   //plot graph here;
}

var plot1  = new obj('#holder1');
var plot2 = new obj('#holder2');
plot1.plot();
plot2.plot();
```

Here, the same bigjsondata will be shared among all objects of obj.